# Multiple lists in binding DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have two ObservableCollection

```
List1 = new ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel>();

List2 = new ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionModel>();
```

Both these lists have their own data. In my xaml, is it possible to bind my Datagrid to two the two different lists? Ideally I want to bind List1 on button1click and List2 on button2click. My xaml is below

```
<DataGrid Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" Margin="0,0,0,50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
    ...
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can't you set your `Itemsource`in the code-behind in the click-handlers?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the ItemsSource twice on a single DataGrid to two different lists.

You can however create a new custom class which will hold both of your ManagementFunctionModel objects in a single class:

```
public class ManagementFunctionPair
{
   public ManagementFunctionModel First { get; set; }
   public ManagementFunctionModel Second { get; set; }
}
```

Then, use an ObservableCollection of ManagementFunctionPair, and bind that to your DataGrid instead:

```
list = new ObservableCollection<ManagementFunctionPair>();
```

Comment: OP, has this answer solved your problem? Are you still having trouble?